# How to open a popup menu of a comboboxedit from code

Tags: c#, winforms, combobox, devexpress

How do I open a popup menu of a `comboboxedit` "`Devexpress Component`" from code (Windows application in C#)?

I can't find a property or method to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to handle the `KeyDown` event and call the `ComboBoxEdit.ShowPopup` method.